# Add external browser to Apanta Studio 3

Tags: aptana

I am trying to add an external browser to Aptana Studio 3 from preferences/Web Browsers and then NEW, which gives me the "Add External Browser" dialog.

When using the "browse" option to point Aptana to Safari in the Applications folder, it gives me a "The location value is not a valid path name" error.

location shows as: /Applications/Safari.app

If I change that to: /Applications/Safari/Contents/MacOs/Safari.app
its still gives me the error.

What should the correct pathname be?

Thanks

**OK found it:**

```
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow OP's solution didn't work out for me. However, if you edit the launch configuration using `Run > Run configurations...` and select your launch config, in the Main tab, where it says "Browser executable" it will actually accept something like `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` (just use the browse button)